# Installing the webp plugin for gimp on Ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gimp, webp

I'm a linux novice and I'm trying to install the webp plugin for gimp on an Ubuntu desktop. I have downloaded the tarball from the download site of gimp and extracted it. I followed the instructions in the readme, but it doesn't work.

It says I first need to install the webp library from google. It can be found here:

http://code.google.com/speed/webp/download.html

But I have no idea how to install it. It's probably something trivial, but being a novice I have no idea what to do next.

I also went to the Ubuntu Software Center and found the same package there and clicked the install button. That seemed to have worked so I think it is installed now.

The readme tells me to issue the following commands:

```
export LIBS=-lwebp
gimptool-2.0 --install file-webp.c
```

And this gives me the following result:

```
gcc  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gimp-2.0   -o /home/pascal/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/file-webp file-webp.c  -lgimpui-2.0 -lgimpwidgets-2.0 -lgimpmodule-2.0 -lgimp-2.0 -lgimpmath-2.0 -lgimpconfig-2.0 -lgimpcolor-2.0 -lgimpbase-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype   -lwebp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried using -libwebp instead of -lwebp, but that gives me the same error message.

**update**

I installed libwebp-dev as well and tried the same command. It solved the error, but now gives me another error:

```
gcc  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gimp-2.0   -o /home/pascal/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/file-webp file-webp.c  -lgimpui-2.0 -lgimpwidgets-2.0 -lgimpmodule-2.0 -lgimp-2.0 -lgimpmath-2.0 -lgimpconfig-2.0 -lgimpcolor-2.0 -lgimpbase-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype   -lwebp
/tmp/cchf3eQS.o: In function `run':
file-webp.c:(.text+0x1b2): undefined reference to `read_webp'
file-webp.c:(.text+0x281): undefined reference to `export_dialog'
file-webp.c:(.text+0x2b5): undefined reference to `write_webp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 4):

The [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) plugin [is included in Gimp 2.10](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GIMP-WebP-Image-Support) as a built-in plugin.

[On older scenarios](https://askubuntu.com/a/633257/349837):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/webp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gimp-webp
```

Also, [in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/788990/349837) (since 16.04):

```
sudo apt install webp
```

Will provide you with these commands:

- `dwebp`: decompress a WebP file to an image file
- `cwebp`: compress an image file to a WebP file
- `webpmux`: create animated WebP files from non-animated WebP images, extract frames from animated WebP images, and manage XMP/EXIF metadata and ICC profile.
- `gif2webp`: Convert a GIF image to WebP
- `vwebp`: decompress a WebP file and display it in a window

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you installed the `webp` package. Instead, install the `libwebp-dev` package.

The [`webp` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/webp) provides CLI binary tools. The [`libwebp-dev` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libwebp-dev) provides the development library needed to compile programs that use `libwebp`.

The compiler flag `-lwebp` causes the compiler the look for a library called `libwebp.a` `libwebp-dev` [provides this file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/libwebp-dev/filelist).

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. However, the installation still fails, now with another error (see update to the question).

I understand your description of the solution. The tarball I downloaded contains the CLI binary tools as well as the library. The file libwebp.a is in there, but I guess the compiler couldn't find it in the path. I don't know how to solve that. Probably by moving the file to the correct location, but I don't know where. However using the installer for that package did it all for me.

Comment: I downloaded the `gimp-webp` code. You can compile the code by running `make`. However, the README instructions are wrong/stale/old; using `gimptool-2.0 --install file-webp.c` only works [if the plug-in consists of only one file](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-scripting.html#gimp-plugins-install). Moreover, that `gimp-webp` package is dated 2012. There is active development being done by Nathan Osman [here](https://github.com/nathan-osman/gimp-webp). Following the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/633257/8005) I managed to install his `webp` plugin on Ubuntu 14.04 / Gimp 2.8.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the instructions and now everything works fine.